# Plot graphs with direction and numbered in Mathematica

Tags: optional-arguments, plotting, slideshows

I would like to write a code in *Mathematica* such that it shows the direction with numbers on points. I wrote this code which does not do this. I want just to complete this code with two options I told. Any Idea. thanks.

```
ListPolarPlot[{Table[{2^n, 1}, {n, 1, 6}]}, Joined -> True,PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red, Green, Yellow, Gray}, Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
data = Reverse@Table[{2^n, 1}, {n, 1, 6}];
Graph[Table[DirectedEdge[i, i + 1], {i, Length@data - 1}], 
  VertexLabels -> "Name", VertexCoordinates -> ({#2 Cos[#1], #2 Sin[#1]} & @@@ data), 
  Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 300]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
foo := Module[{r = Transpose@Through[{Cos, Sin}[2^Range[#]]], p},
              p = Partition[r, 2, 1]; 
              Graphics[{Opacity[.5], Red, Disk[#, .05] & /@ r, Opacity[1],
                        Black, Text @@@ MapIndexed[{First@#2, #} &, r],
                        Arrow[#, .05] & /@ p},
                        PlotRange -> {{-1.2, 1.2}, {-1.2, 1.2}}]] &

foo@8
```

[image]

```
ListAnimate[Table[foo[i], {i, 2, 50}], AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

[image]

Edit: post-processing `ListPolarPlot` output as in eldo's answer:

```
 n = 14; 
 Block[{i = 1, xx = {}}, 
  ListPolarPlot[Partition[Thread@{2^Range[n], 1}, 2, 1], 
               Joined -> True, BaseStyle -> Arrowheads[.05], 
               PlotStyle -> (Hue /@ (Range[n]/n))] /. 
    Line[x_] :> {Disk[x[[1]], .07], 
                 Text[Style[i++, 14, Black], x[[1]]], Arrow[xx = x, .05]} /. 
    Arrow[xx, .05] :> {GrayLevel[.7], Disk[xx[[2]], .07], 
                       Text[Style[i++, 14, Black], xx[[2]]], Arrow[xx, .05]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
PolarGraph[n_Integer] :=
 Module[{lp = ListPolarPlot @ Table[{2^x, 1}, {x, 1, n}], p, a, t},
  p = Reverse @ Take [Cases[lp, {_Real, _Real}, -1], n];
  a = Arrow /@ Partition[p, 2, 1];
  t = Text @@@ Transpose[{Range @ Length @ p, p}] /.
    Text[u_, v_] :> Text[Style[u, Red, 16], v + 0.1];
  Graphics[{a, t}, Axes -> True]]

PolarGraph[7]
```

[image]